# Remove string starting with certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am manipulating some content that I receive from an API. At the end of the main text field, The api sometimes returns the string below:

```
@@canvas-link@@{"type":"doc","fileName":"xyzv2.jpg","fileExt":"jpg",
         "fileSize":"232352",
               "file":"405957767101","downloadUrl":"dummytext"}
```

What is the best way to remove this string from the main text field?

Comment: What language are you working with/

Comment: @RyanDawkins - Read the tags.

Comment: @JosephSilber oh. Thanks, guess I'll just upvote you then.

Comment: what the hells `@@canvas-link@@`? Doesn't look like javascript?

Comment: @Liam: *"The api sometimes returns the **string** below"*. No one is saying it's JavaScript.

Comment: whoops, should have said I am working with javascript/jquery. the content returned is meta data basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure it's at the end, this version is **fastest**;

```
s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("@@canvas-link@@")) ; // FASTER than most
```

but **updated** Just for fun, I've another variant using `slice()` which is slightly faster in this test even than `substring()`.

```
s.slice(0,s.lastIndexOf("@@canvas-link@@")); // FASTEST
```

Here's a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/so-17535719) which shows them beating both RegEx and split. Although I'm surprised split wasn't quicker.

However, your mileage may vary, and for more complex scenarios I'd expect RegEx (replace) to come out on top.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = str.replace(/@@canvas-link@@.*/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving Joseph Silbers,

```
str = str.replace(/@@canvas-link@@{.*}/, '');
```

To make sure it doesn't remove anything after.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, but a `split()` will avoid complications with carriage returns.

```
var str = 'foobar@@canvas-link@@{"type":"doc","fileName":"xyzv2.jpg","fileExt":"jpg",
     "fileSize":"232352",
           "file":"405957767101","downloadUrl":"dummytext"}';
var data = str.split('@@canvas-link@@')[0];
console.log(data);

>> foobar
```

Comment: this appears to be removing all the text in the object